# Can remote computer log incoming keystrokes from TeamViewer?

Tags: remote-desktop, passwords, teamviewer, keystrokes

Let's say I connect to a remote computer with TeamViewer.  On the remote computer I open an application that requires a password to run.  The password field is masked, i.e. as I type it displays ******.  Is it possible for the remote user to somehow log or otherwise obtain the incoming keystrokes and therefore the password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Can the remote user log the incoming keystrokes and therefore the password?

Yes, if there is monitoring software (for example a keystroke logger) enabled on the remote machine.

> Teamviewer indicates they secure their connections client to client.
>
> If implemented properly this should mean no one can intercept the data
>   you send over the network in plain text, i.e. find you password and
>   username, because the connection is encrypted.
>
> In other words, in the case you describe (you connecting to your home
>   computer) it should be secure, assuming you don't have any
>   malware/keylogger running on your pc (but again: that has nothing to
>   do with Teamviewer).
>
> The same may not be true if you connect via Teamviewer to a client his
>   computer. Not because the connection is not secure, but because the PC
>   you are connecting to might have monitoring software enabled.
>
> https://www.teamviewer.com/en/products/security.aspx

Source [Teamviewer and remote logins](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/101903/78564) answer by [user3244085](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/40873/user3244085)